# Animating views separately within a RecyclerView

Tags: android, animation, gridview, android-recyclerview

I haven't investigated this much yet, however I haven't seen a feature such as this done before or found much information regarding the subject, so I thought it would be best to reach out to SO to see if anyone has toyed with this idea before and could provide any advice. If not, I'll post the solution below when I find it.

---

### Desired Outcome

Currently I have a `GridView` populated with content. I have a `FloatingActionButton` on top of the `GridView` and when the user taps on the FAB, I would like to display a new `View`. When tapped, I want each individual `GridView` item to rotate and move towards the edge of the screen resulting in the whole `GridView` parting to make room for the new `View` to slide in from the bottom. The `RecyclerView` will become unscrollable when the secondary `View` is present, and will stay that way until the user goes back, doing so would result in the opposite animation occurring bringing the `ViewHolder`s back into the centre and closing the gap.

---

Excuse me for my appauling attempt at drawing my problem. :)

*GridView pre-animation*
[image]

*GridView after animation*
[image]

Each view item should animate independently from one another and the end animation will simulate a kind of exploding `RecyclerView` effect.

---

### Possible Approach / Attempted so Far

I am currently reading up on the behaviour of the individual elements of the `RecyclerView`. I also got some pretty good information from this [Android Summit video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc_Tt7q77qwyKRgytF1RzRx8&v=imsr8NrIAMs) about `RecyclerView` animations.

Right now I think there are a couple of different approache:

1. Using two different `LayoutManager`s and attempting to animate between them.
2. Using an `ItemDecorator` to alter each `ViewHolder`s margins and angle.

---

Any advice or recommendations will be greatly appreciated, I'll update the above list as I work through the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being able to animate the views within a RecyclerView turned out to be very simple! All you need is a custom `RecyclerView.LayoutManager` and you then have access to all the views which are visible for your animating pleasure.

The main method here is `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt(int index)`, with both of these methods as seen below in `getVisibleViews()` you have access to all of the views which the `RecyclerView` is currently displaying. I then use a simple `View.animate()` call to animate each view to the desired X position and rotation. I'm sure this will work with all other types of animations too! I now have exactly what I wanted. :)

Here's the custom LayoutManager, remember if you don't extend a predefined `LayoutManager` such as `GridLayoutManager` or `LinearLayoutManager` you'll need to supply more methods such as `generateDefaultLayoutParams()`.

```
public class AnimatingGridLayoutManager extends GridLayoutManager {

private static final int PARTED_ANIMATION_DURATION = 200;
private static final int PARTED_ANIMATION_VARIANCE = 20;
private static final int PARTED_ANIMATION_OFFSET = 25;
private static final int PARTED_ANIMATION_ANGLE = 15;

private boolean itemsParted;

...

public void setItemsParted(boolean itemsParted, Activity context) {
    Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;

    if (this.itemsParted != itemsParted) {
        this.itemsParted = itemsParted;
        if (itemsParted) {
            partItems(context, screenWidth);
        } else {
            closeItems(screenWidth);
        }
    }
}

private void partItems(Context context, int screenWidth) {
    List<View> visibleViews = getVisibleViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < visibleViews.size(); i++) {
        int viewWidth = visibleViews.get(i).getWidth();
        int offset = ViewUtils.getPixelsFromDp(getRandomNumberNearInput(PARTED_ANIMATION_OFFSET), context);
        int xPos = (-viewWidth) + offset;
        int rotation = getRandomNumberNearInput(-PARTED_ANIMATION_ANGLE);

        if (viewPositionIsRight(i)) {
            // invert values to send view to end of screen instead of start
            xPos = screenWidth - offset;
            rotation = -rotation;
        }

        visibleViews.get(i).animate()
            .x(xPos)
            .rotation(rotation)
            .setDuration(PARTED_ANIMATION_DURATION)
            .setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
    }
}

private void closeItems(int screenWidth) {
    List<View> visibleViews = getVisibleViews();
    for (int i = 0; i < visibleViews.size(); i++) {
        int xPos = 0;

        if (viewPositionIsRight(i)) {
            xPos = screenWidth / 2;
        }

        visibleViews.get(i).animate()
            .x(xPos)
            .rotation(0)
            .setDuration(PARTED_ANIMATION_DURATION)
            .setInterpolator(new FastOutSlowInInterpolator());
    }
}

private boolean viewPositionIsRight(int position) {
    // if isn't 2 row grid new logic is needed
    return position % 2 != 0;
}

private int getRandomNumberNearInput(int input) {
    Random random = new Random();
    int max = input + PARTED_ANIMATION_VARIANCE;
    int min = input - PARTED_ANIMATION_VARIANCE;
    return random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
}

private List<View> getVisibleViews() {
    List<View> visibleViews = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
        visibleViews.add(getChildAt(i));
    }
    return visibleViews;
}
}
```